# Vue conditionally load Vue.use plugins

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am using webpack conditional imports to conditionally load my Vue components, for example:

```
Vue.component('my-comp', () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Components/MyComp" */ 'Components/MyComp'));

new Vue({
  el: '#vue_app',
});
```

All works as expected, the component import is only included if it used.

I am wondering if the same can be achieved for `Vue.use`. For example I am using the [vue-textra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-textra) package, which is included like this:

```
import Textra from 'vue-textra';
Vue.use(Textra);
```

However, I would like to do something like this:

```
Vue.use(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue-textra" */ 'vue-textra'));
```

The above does not work.

When I look at the plugin definition, all it is doing is registering a component:

```
var Textra = {
  install: function install(Vue) {
    Vue.component("textra", TextraPlugin);
  }
};
```

Although I am using the above as a specific example, I suppose that some plugins will not register components and I wonder if conditional loading can apply for those plugins too.

Comment: First, I think there is no conditional imports. The `import(...)` is dynamic import and webpack uses it to split your code to multiple files and load it when needed. So if you don't want to load the plugin at very first then you can just import and install it inside the component you use. If that component is imported as dynamic import, the plugin should be only packed to that file.

Comment: If you really want to split that plugin to another file too. I believe this should work `import(...).then(module => Vue.use(module))`(may be `module.default` not sure).

Comment: @User28 - yes sorry they are not conditional imports. But Vue takes the promise returned by the dynamic import and conditionally loads it when it sees that component used. I was wondernig if `Vue.use()` could do the same, but I guess it is far more complicated due to not knowing "when the plugin is used". Your second comment example would work for sure